# What is {{.}} in mustache?

Tags: mustache

I'm starting to look through some mustache templates and I've come across something that I don't understand/haven't been able to find an explanation for.

```
{{#something}}word-here={{.}}{{/something}}
```

Can someone help me understand what the `{{.}}` is doing?

Comment: is `#something` an array? It just displays the current item in the list.

Comment: Should be a numeric value

Comment: It is obviously there to point out how awesome mustaches are.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Mustache, `{{.}}` is a special tag referring to the value at the top of the context stack. If you're looping through an array, it is the current element. If you're rendering a section with an object as context, it refers to that object.

https://github.com/mustache/spec/blob/master/specs/interpolation.yml#L7-L9

So if your data looks like this:

```
{
  numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  string: 'Wheee!'
}
```

… and you've got a template like this:

```
{{# numbers }}
 * {{ . }}
{{/ numbers }}
```

… it will render as this:

```
 * 1
 * 2
 * 3
 * 4
 * 5
```

If your template looks like this:

```
{{# string }}{{ . }}{{/ string }}
```

… it will render as this:

```
Wheee!
```

For more on the context stack, see the Mustache.php wiki:

https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/wiki/Variable-Resolution

*Edit: I just realized this tag is in the Mustache wiki, under "implicit iterator":*

https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/wiki/Mustache-Tags#implicit-iterator

Answer (score 1):

```
{{#something}}word-here={{.}}{{/something}}
```

The above syntax is used to iterate over an indexed array or an indexed list in Mustache.
So you have an indexed array or a list named "**something**", then you are iterating over this array and using its values by denoting the iterated value with "**.**" *(with the surrounded brackets, which means it is Mustache syntax)*.

Credits: http://dwellupper.io/post/22/accessing-array-values-in-mustache-php

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't comment on this account but I will use the answer thing as a comment.

variables `{{variableName}}` are available in moustache, you probably knew that. I believe that moustache variables may be allowed to be `{{.}}` and do not have to be just alphabetic or numberic. They may accept underscores and such. It's possible that they don't follow regular variable naming conventions. I am not sure and have never tested it before, you should. Also, empty variables that don't exist (null value) are ignored when the file is compiled, so you may just ignore this(depending).

Comment: The . does not appear to be a variable. At least not one defined in the code/templates that I am accessing.

Comment: So, it may be treated as a null value, and therefore ignored. I do not see anything in the moustache doc that mentions a {{.}} Try to remove it and see if the code compiles and works

Comment: It just is the current item, if it is `something is a number` it will just display the number, if it is an array it'l just loop through and print them one by one... repeating the content. If there is no value, null/undefined for the property the entire section will be ignored.

Comment: I tried naming a variable `.` in quotes and got the error: `[object Object]` I tried it outside of the quotes and it worked. I did, also find something interesting. It doesn't follow naming conventions. The variable may be started with a digit O.o

Comment: @J.Miller Is `word-here=` being rendered in your template?

Comment: @nousernamesremained Not sure. The system that the templates are a part of is runnable, however not particularly easily. It's very large, and I'm not entirely sure how/where the templates fit in. Hence I was trying to figure out without. I think that it is likely that PSL is correct.

Comment: alright. I learnt that moustache has weird variable naming :P